# iOS Table View Datasource in Different Class

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a simple iOS app in which one class called `Dictionary` (.m and .h) has several functions for building an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects and then functions to manipulate that data structure.  I have a `UITableViewController` class that has the table view delegate methods, but I can't figure out how to create an instance of the `Dictionary` class in that `UIViewController` in order to be able to have all of the delegate methods talk to that instance of the class (e.g. when i call `Dictionary *dictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init]` in the `viewDidLoad` method, I can't access any of that instance in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.  New to iOS programming and feeling very frustrated with it!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to declare dictionary as a member variable of your class.
There are several ways to do this. The quickest is to put the following above the @implementation call in your .m file of your table view controller.

```
@interface nameOftableViewControllerClass(){
    Dictionary *dictionary;
}
@end
```

Make sure to replace nameOftableViewControllerClass with the actual name of your view controller class.
Then, in view did load. you can call the following

```
dictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init];
```

Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you can call any functions on the dictionary object.
Don't forget to put a release call in the dealloc method of your table view controller.

```
-(void) dealloc {
     [dictionary release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

hope this helps, hit my up if you have any more problems

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you!  If i am using ARC with iOS 5, would i still need a dealloc call?

Comment: Hi John, not sure if you figured this out yet or not, but if you are using ARC you do not need to release your objects, they will be garbage collected. I'm just one of those programmers who is really anal about having control of his memory :)

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary variable you declared that way is local to the viewDidLoad method. Instead, declare it as property of the ViewController, assign the Dictionary to it and then access it in your delegate methods (e.g. self.dictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init] ).